# Invalid Qualifier Compile Error when sending multiple fields to new folders in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, compiler-errors

I'm struggling to figure out what I need to do in order to run this code. I've based almost the entire thing off of this question:

[MS Access VBA download attachment Mkdir path not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51310123/ms-access-vba-download-attachment-mkdir-path-not-exist)

In which we have similar objectives, except mine is to send all fields from a table to two new folders based off of two fields "engine" and "testtype" rather than "year" and "month" as in the question posted above^.

I'm very new to VBA programming (basically started two weeks ago), and am open to any suggestions.  Basically, I set the Dim for Record 1 as a string so that the field value could be read and not have an error pop up. But, I'm still using the code from the question above at the end of the script, and I'm not sure if I should keep it in, given my objective. The question above has multiple attachments in one field, whereas I just have multiple fields with strings in their records.

I'm getting the error message at the "While Not Record1.EOF" line.

Please advise if possible!

```
Sub Eng_Test()
Dim database As DAO.database
Dim table As DAO.Recordset
Dim PONum As String
Dim folder As String
Dim Record1 As String
Set database = CurrentDb
Dim PKey As String
Dim P2Key As String
Set table = database.OpenRecordset("tblFieldLogNOAUTO#")

folder = "C:\users"
If Len(Dir(folder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir folder
End If
folder = folder & "\ndemos"
If Len(Dir(folder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir folder
End If
folder = folder & "\ONEDRIVE"
If Len(Dir(folder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir folder
End If
folder = folder & "\Documents"
If Len(Dir(folder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir folder
End If
```

```
With table
    Do Until .EOF
    Record1 = table.Fields("TimeDateTeam").Value
    'Record2 = table.Fields("frmDate").Value
    'Record3 = table.Fields("Location").Value
    'Record4 = table.Fields("Engine").Value
    'Record5 = table.Fields("TestType").Value
    'Record6 = table.Fields("Data Locator").Value
    'Record7 = table.Fields("Calibration File").Value
    'Record8 = table.Fields("Engine Serial").Value
    'Record9 = table.Fields("VIN Number").Value
    'Record10 = table.Fields("Moe Number").Value
    'Record11 = table.Fields("Name/Team").Value
    'Records = Record1 & Record2 & Record3 & Record4 & Record5 & Record6 & Record7 & Record8 & Record9 & Record10 & Record11

    PKey = table.Fields("Engine").Value
    If Len(Dir(folder & "\" & PKey, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir folder & "\" & PKey
    End If
    
    P2Key = table.Fields("TestType").Value
    If Len(Dir(folder & "\" & PKey & "\" & P2Key, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir folder & "\" & PKey & "\" & P2Key
    End If
    
    Eng_TestFolder = folder & "\" & PKey & "\" & P2Key
    
    
    While Not Record1.EOF
    
        Record1.Fields("FileData").SaveToFile (Eng_TestFolder)
        Record1.MoveNext
    
    Wend
    .MoveNext

Loop
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You set `Record1` to the value of a field. It does not have a `EOF` property, nor does it have a `Fields` collection, or a `MoveNext` method.

Comment: If your fields just have strings and you are NOT trying to extract objects from attachment field, what are you trying to accomplish? Where do you expect this string data to go to in a folder? String data is not a file.

Comment: @braX , thank you for pointing that out to me. Aside from trying to put the field values into the folders, I'm still unable to create the folders in the first place. I commented out each of the things that had to do with the end goal of placing the field values in a folder within a folder.  When I run the code, everything runs smoothly and vba doesn't throw anything back at me besides a message box I told to tell me that the folders had been created. Only, when I search for the folders in the specified directory, they aren't there.